# Laravel Session Conflicts

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a quiz system with several quizzes.
Playing a quiz is fully made with AJAX calls (and jQuery appends).

An answer has a status (0 or 1) with 0 being wrong and 1 being the right answer.

Inside my PHP function I check if the answer status == 1, and if thats the case I put a variable inside my session so so in the end I can get the Session and check how many right answers have been given.

The session results are completely unreliable with as outcomes randomly given 0 or 1, and it never adds up.

What is going wrong that it always return 1, or null although there has been more correct answers given?

PHP Function

```
public function checkAnswer(Request $request)
{
    $currentQuestionId = $request->currentQuestionId;
    $chosenAnswer = $request->answer;

    if ($chosenAnswer == 'null') {
        return;
    }

    $answer = Answer::where('question_id', '=', $currentQuestionId)
        ->where('name', '=', $chosenAnswer)->get();

    if (($answer[0]->status) == 1) {
        $answers = $request->session()->get('correctAnswers', 0);

        if ($answers == 0) {

            echo 'if';
            $i = 0;
            $request->session()->put('correctAnswers', 1);
        }
        else {
            echo 'else';
            $i = $request->session()->get('correctAnswers');
            $request->session()->put('correctAnswers', $i++);
        }
    }
}
```

jQuery AJAX Function

```
// CHECKING ANSWER WITH AJAX CALL
var answer = $('input[name=answer]:checked').val(),
        currentQuestionId = $('.question').attr('id'),
        token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/quiz/' + {{$quiz[0]->id}} +'/check',
    data: {
        'currentQuestionId': currentQuestionId,
        'answer': answer,
        '_token': token
    },
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) you return data ONLY if first question answered correctly.
2) if you want to find only one row - use ->first() instead of ->get()
3) $request->session()->put('correctAnswers', $answers ++); instead of if/else

Comment: $('input[name=answer]:checked') change to $('input[name="answer"]:checked')